# c++ std::regex doesn't match as expected

Tags: c++, regex

I've tried to implement a simple string-test method using c++ std::regex, in MS VC++ 2012.

```
const std::string str = "1.0.0.0029.443";

if ( std::regex_match( str, std::regex( "\\.0\\d+" ) ) )
    std::cout << "matched." << std::endl;
```

I guessed that the code would match ".0029" part of the given str. However, it doesn't match at all.
I tried it on http://regex101.com/ and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::regex_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) instead to return your submatch.

```
const std::string str = "1.0.0.0029.443";

std::regex rgx("(\\.0[0-9]+)");
std::smatch match;

if (std::regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), match, rgx)) {
    std::cout << match[1] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) reports an *exact match*, i.e., the entire input string must match the regex.

To match subsequences, use [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your regex matches **the full string** and nothing else, you need something like this:

```
^(?:\d+\.)*\d+$
```

This translates into

```
if ( std::regex_match( str, std::regex( "^(?:\\d+\\.)*\\d+$" ) ) )
    std::cout << "matched." << std::endl;
```

The beginning and end of anchors `^` and `$` are required, otherwise you might match a string in the middle of `BANANA_0.1.12AND_APPLE`